# Why some lines in Bash history become "*"?

Tags: bash

Why some lines (as below line 509 and 512 ) in Bash history become "*", after I execute reverse-i-search?

```
507  stty -ixon
508  history
509* 
510  echo 10
511  echo 20
512* 
513  ls
514  history
515  stty ixon
516  stty -a
517  stty -h
518  man stty
519  history
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The star means the line has been modified. See `man history`.

Demonstration:

From the terminal prompt use the up-arrow key to display a previous command.
Delete the command with the backspace key.
Use the down-arrow key to return to the last prompt and enter
history
The modified line should now be displayed in the history as a line number followed by a star.

Comment: Relevant section of the [bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-History-Builtins): "Lines prefixed with a ‘*’ have been modified."

Comment: If you backspace and then hit Enter, you will have issued a new command. The * will be shown only next to commands you began to edit and then navigated away from. (By the way, you can return these commands to their unedited state by navigating to them and hitting `Ctrl+_` repeatedly.)

Comment: @Noumenon Control + _  is the S**t. Thanks.

Comment: @Noumenon Ctrl + _ changes font size on my screen. Any other way to do this?

Comment: @sureshvv Try `Ctrl+Shift+_`, it works for me.

Comment: @Noumenon no luck on my ubuntu 20.04 Shall try again after upgrade

Answer (score 18):

`*` Asterisk is an indication as well, that the commands were run from a different session. You can check this by opening two terminal windows, running bunch of commands and checking `history` on both. Asterisk will only appear on the commands the other window executed.