# What does the asterisk character mean next to history item in shell?

Tags: bash, shell

From time to time in my `iTerm` (`macOS Sierra`) I type `history` to get a list of recently used commands.

I noticed that some of them are appended with an asterisk character.

```
 3254  code
 3255  gulp
 3256* cd foo
 3257* youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch\?v\=xxxxxxxxxxx
 3258  ls
```

What is the purpose of `*` character in lines *3256* and *3257*?

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](https://ss64.com/bash/history.html)

> With no options, display the history list with line numbers. Lines
>   prefixed with with a `*` have been modified.

*EDIT*

[Demonstration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238804/why-some-lines-in-bash-history-become):

From the terminal prompt use the up-arrow key to display a previous command. Delete the command with the backspace key. Use the down-arrow key to return to the last prompt and enter history The modified line should now be displayed in the history as a line number followed by a star.

Comment: Nice, but how can a history entry be modified, and by what?